# array shuffle and undo

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

as code below,

```php
<?php
// sort array in a fixed order with given seed
function do_shuffle( $array, $seed ) {
    mt_srand( $seed );
    usort( $array, fn() => mt_rand( - 9, 9 ) );
    return $array;
}

// the reverse operation of do_shuffle
function undo_shuffle( $array, $seed ) {
    return $array; // to implement
}

$origin_array = str_split( 'olive tree' );

$seed = 20220502;

$shuffled_array = do_shuffle( $origin_array, $seed );
var_dump( $shuffled_array );

// undo shuffle
$origin_array = undo_shuffle( $shuffled_array, $seed );
var_dump( $origin_array );
```

how to implement array shuffle and its reverse operation?

how to return $shuffled_array to $origin_array?

Comment: You can't reverse random shuffle. Just keep the original array and show it if needed, it would work like 'undoing' the shuffle

Comment: @Lothric but it's not random as you think, it's based on the seed so he will just keep the seed but he can't find how to reverse it if it's random will generate multiple possibilities not only just one result.

Comment: create backup variable / alias re assign when required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key idea is to recreate a process but shuffle not the array values but array indices. This gives us a mapping between shuffled and original indices:

```
// the reverse operation of do_shuffle
function undo_shuffle( $array, $seed ) {
    mt_srand( $seed );

    $indices_map = range(0, count($array) - 1);

    // We do just the same shuffle operation but
    // shuffling array indices instead of values
    usort( $indices_map, function(){ 
      return mt_rand( - 9, 9 );
    } );

    // Restore original array using the map we've created
    $out = [];
    foreach( $indices_map as $shuffled_index => $original_index )
      $out[ $original_index ] = $array[ $shuffled_index ];

    // Sort our output by integer key
    ksort($out);

    return $out;
}
```